# Ползунок ui и jcarousel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Есть карусель jcarousel, которая прокручивается при помощи кнопок вперед-назад и ползунка ui.

Когда нажимаешь на кнопки и медленно перемещаешь ползунок, то всё работает нормально. Проблема возникает, когда ползунок перемещается быстро. Предположим, он переместился на 5 позиций, а карусель прокручивается только 3 раза. Код:

```
 $('.ui_slider').slider({  
          value: 1,
          min: min,
          max: max,
          slide: function(event, ui) {
          if (last_val > ui['value']) {
    var step = last_val - ui['value']; //считаем, на сколько позиций сдвинули ползунок
    for(var i=0;i<step;i++) $(".jcarousel-prev").click(); //лстаем назад

            } else {
            var step = ui['value']-last_val;
            for(var i=0;i<step;i++)  $('.jcarousel-next').click(); //листаем вперед
```

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

привяжите позицию ползунка к номеру картинки.

```
$('.jcarousel').jcarousel('scroll', N);
```

чтобы было плавно сделайте интерполяцию позиций ползунка в количество картинок (через пропорцию)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)